# How to improve this script. Dividing a column by 3 in openpyxl

Tags: python, loops, division, calculated-columns, openpyxl

Looking for a way to simplify the division of a column. Is there a loop I can use?

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook

xfile = load_workbook('camdatatest.xlsx')

sheet =xfile.get_sheet_by_name('Sheet1')

sheet['D2'] = '=C2/3' # Want to divide all values in Column C with the new value in D.
sheet['D3'] = '=C4/3'
sheet['D4'] = '=C5/3'
sheet['D5'] = '=C6/3'
sheet['D6'] = '=C7/3'
sheet['D7'] = '=C8/3'
sheet['D8'] = '=C9/3'
sheet['D9'] = '=C10/3'




xfile.save("camdatatestoutput.xlsx")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is just one of the possibilities.

```
for i in range(2,11):
    sheet['D{}'.format(i)] = '=C{}/3'.format(i)
```

Notice that the way `range` works if you want the number 10 to be included, you need to make sure to pass in 11.

Comment: Thanks! You have my upvote! One more question, if possible? What if I want to divide the range for a column by subsequent or changing values from a separate column, such that..........for i in range(2,11): sheet['D{}'.format(i)] = 'C{}/G2,G3,G4,etc...??

Comment: that's quite possible, you need to change the format that's all. Please accept this and post another question if you need details.

Comment: I may have not explained that well. I would like to divide C1/G1, C2,G2, C3,G3, etc.. and place the result in a new column.

Comment: that's still a new question

Comment: great. Will try to answer.